# Docker is returns 'bad address' for some local domains

Tags: linux, docker

My Docker instance returns 'bad address' for some local domains.

Here are the pings to server-1 and server-2 from host server that works fine.

```
root@my-server:/# ping server-1.local.dev

PING server-1.local.dev (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from server-1.local.dev (192.168.1.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.540 ms
```

```
root@my-server:/# ping server-2.local.dev

PING server-2.local.dev (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from server-2.local.dev (192.168.1.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
```

Here is the ping from docker to server-1 which is fine.

```
root@my-server:/# docker run -it --dns 192.168.1.1 --rm alpine ping server-1.local.dev

PING server-1.local.dev (192.168.1.2): 56 data bytes

64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.429 ms
```

Here is the ping that results in bad address from docker to server-2.

```
root@my-server:/# docker run -it --dns 192.168.1.1 --rm alpine ping server-2.local.dev

ping: bad address 'server-2.local.dev'
```

This is the host resolv.conf

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Could you help me understand why the docker is persistently failing to recognize the server-2 domain?

tried everything but failed!